# How can I find the distance between two elements React Native?

Tags: react-native

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Animated, UIManager, findNodeHandle, PanResponder } from 'react-native';

const TestScreen = props => {

    const myPosition = useRef();
    const enemyPosition = useRef();

    return (
        <View style={styles.main}>
            <View style={styles.screenLeft}>
                <Animated.View ref={myPosition}>
                    <View style={styles.fighter} >
                    </View>
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.screenRight}>
                <Animated.View ref={enemyPosition}>
                    <View style={styles.enemy}>
                    </View>
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    screenLeft: {
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        position: 'absolute'
    },
    screenRight: {
        alignItems: 'flex-end'
    },
    fighter: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        width: 20,
        height: 50
    },
    enemy: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
        width: 20,
        height: 50
    }
});

export default TestScreen;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV0dT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Dimensions

```
 import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

Then get the windowWidth

```
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

According to your case, it should be windowWidth - 40

= windowWidth -20 (the left hand side box) -20 (the right hand side box)